# How to set up gcloud to use credentials from identity federation with OIDC

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sdk, gcloud-cli

On [this page](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/access-resources-oidc#generate), it is explained how to set up workload identity federation and how to use it with the (Python) client libraries.

This is done by setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. However, this does not work for the gcloud SDK itself, as this uses other methods for configuring credentials.

Normally, using a service account key, one would run `gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=KEY_FILE`, but this does not work for workload identity federation credentials.

How can you set up gcloud to use workload identity federation from an OIDC identity provider?

Comment: I think this is not possible at the moment. It might be helpful for you to open a Customer Issue on [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=0) so that they can confirm if this is indeed impossible and perhaps open a feature request to implement this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have created an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187734550)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from gcloud SDK version 363.0.0, this can now be done using the `--cred-file` flag:

```
gcloud auth login --cred-file=/path/to/workload/identity/config/file
```

(You might need to add a `--brief` flag as well)

Note: earlier versions might work as well as it was already present but undocumented before 363.0.0

Source: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#36300_2021-11-02